# Test failed - ProductService is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am using `"chai": "^4.2.0",` and `"mocha": "^4.0.1"`. I am running `node --version`,  `v10.15.3` My goal is to test the Service-Layer:

My `ProductService.js` looks like the following:

```
class ProductService {

    constructor() {
        // constructor
    }

    async createOrUpdateProduct(dataArray) {
        return "done"
    }
}

module.exports = {
    ProductService
};
```

My test class `ProductTestService.js` looks like the following:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

const ProductService = require('../Service/ProductService')


describe('Product model', () => {

    it('should add the test data with the Products Service to the Product table', async () => {
        let dataArr = "product data"
        let productServ = new ProductService()

        const res = await productServ.createOrUpdateProduct(dataArr)
        assert.isOk(res.length, dataArr.length);
    });

});
```

When running the tests, I get:

[image]

Any suggestions why the instantiation does not work?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```js
module.exports = {
    ProductService
};
```

Is shorthand for

```js
module.exports = {
    ProductService: ProductService
};
```

This means that, when you import the module with

```js
const ProductService = require('../Service/ProductService');
```

The value of `ProductService` is exactly what you exported, i.e. an object with a property ProductService.

```js
{
    ProductService: ProductService
}
```

To fix your problem, either export the class directly, if it's the only thing you want to export from the module

```js
module.exports = ProductService;
```

Or import using object destructuring, if you also want to export other things

```js
const { ProductService } = require('../Service/ProductService');
```